# Default Link text

Tags: feature-request

The default link text is "link text". No one in their right mind ever wants to use that as the link text. Perhaps it would be better if the page title (at least for stack overflow pages) were suggested instead?

Comment: I always create my links by hand. Which works better when you have multiple links to the same url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Click here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21304/me-no-rikey)?

Most people usually only add links in after they've selected the text. In which case, the whole "link text" thing is already swapped out.

Also, it's more than likely that since it's logic related that they would be in their left mind.

Comment: The default text should be illogical to help those who are in their right mind.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that nobody in their right mind would want to use that as the link text is intentional.  The whole point is that the text be something that you **really should change**.

I admit that it would be nice if, for SO questions, the page title were used.  But again, this is one of those little nice-to-have things that's going to be so far down the priority list that, barring some serendipitous randomness in the dev team's planning process, it probably won't get done.